# Mandrill ignores line breaks (\n)

Tags: mandrill

Using the [`send-template`](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template) method and the [Lutung Mandrill Java API](https://github.com/rschreijer/lutung) implementation, when a template variable contains line breaks of the form `\n`, they are totally ignored or stripped on generated emails. The `String`s containing `\n` characters are kept untouched untill the `GET` `send-template` method is executed. So I guess there is some `String` analysis and conversion on Mandrill servers which removes special characters.

How can I make work again line breaks on Mandrill emails?

Answer (score 6):

In my case I am using Handlebars for mandrill templates and I have solved this by sending HTML to the template `<br/>` instead of `\n` by replacing `\n` in my string with `<br/>` something like: `.Description.Replace("\n", "<br/>");`

And then on the mandrill template I put the variable inside {{{ variable }}} instead of {{ variable }}

http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html

> **HTML escaping**
>
> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by an
>   `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use
>   the "triple-stash", "{{{.
>
> In your template:
>
> `<div>   {{{html_tag_content}}} </div>` In your API request:

```
   "global_merge_vars": [   {
      "name": "html_tag_content",
      "content": "This example<br>is all about<br>the magical world of handlebars"   } ]
```

> The result:
>
> This example
>   is all about
>   the magical world of handlebars

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send more complex content, be it html, or variables with break lines and whatnot, you can first render the template and then send the message, instead of directly using `send-template`.

Render the template with a call to [`templates.render`](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html#method=render):

```
{
    "key": "example key",
    "template_name": "Example Template",
    "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "editable",
            "content": "<div>content to inject *|MERGE1|*</div>"
        }
    ],
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "name": "merge1",
            "content": "merge1 content\n contains line breaks"
        }
    ]
}
```

Save the result to a variable `rendered_content`.

Send the message using the rendered template with [`messages.send`](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send):

```
{
    "message": {
        "html": rendered_content,
        ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's a bit too vague.

Comment: @AlonDahari I've added a simple example to better explain what I meant