# How to get a Mandrill/Mailchimp template to preserve line breaks in a merge tag

Tags: django, mailchimp, mandrill

I am using Djrill together with a mailchimp template.

I use this snippet below to push the merge_vars into my template :

```
 msg.global_merge_vars = {
 SNAME': fullname, 'SEMAIL': from_email,'SMESSAGE': message
            }
```

The message *|SMESSAGE|* appears in the email however the line breaks arent preserved. How would I go about keeping the line breaks from my message?

Also please not I cant use {% autoescape on %} method as the template is sent from mailchimp

Comment: Djrill passes merge_vars directly to Mandrill, so what you're really asking is how to get a Mandrill/Mailchimp template to preserve line breaks in a merge tag. Someone [asked that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826425/mandrill-ignores-line-breaks-n) a few months ago, with no answer. You might try something like `<pre>*|SMESSAGE|*</pre>` in your template, or you could encode the message to html with `<br>`'s in your Django code and then use `*|HTML:SMESSAGE|*` in your template (but watch out for script injection!).

Comment: I added the .replace('\r\n',r).replace('\n\r',r).replace('\r',r).replace('\n',r) to my form.cleaned_data and it seemed to work by just declaring *|SMESSAGE|*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this worked for me, I did a str replace on my cleaned message

```
r = '<br />'
message = form.cleaned_data['message'].replace('\r\n',r).replace('\n\r',r).replace('\r',r).replace('\n',r)
```

Then merged it the same way

```
msg.global_merge_vars = {
 SNAME': fullname, 'SEMAIL': from_email,'SMESSAGE': message
            }
```

And declared it in my mailchimp template

```
<p> *|SMESSAGE|* </p>
```

Comment: Whenever you're generating html, it's important to escape any html in the user's input. Django has an [escape function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape) you can use. (Since your html is going into email, [script injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML_script_injection) may not be a *huge* concern, but it's good to be safe. Also, check whether &, < or > work if the user enters them in the message.)

Comment: I think I also had to use `*|HTML:MESSAGE|*`.